# Why ctx.redirect doesn't prevent the code from continuing to execute

Tags: node.js, koa

I'm a little confused about the function of ctx.redirect in koa and nodejs.

```
try {
  let user = await db.collection("user").findOne({"username":username, "password":password});
  if (!user) ctx.redirect('/error');
  console.log("can run here");
} catch (e) {
  ctx.body = {error:true, msg: e instanceof Error ? e.message : e};
}
```

I thought if the user exists, it will prints `can run here`, conversely, it will not print `can run here` if the user does not exist.

But if the user does not exist, it still prints `can run here`, and I tried change the code to `if (!user) ctx.redirect('/error'); return;`, the code does not continue to execute whether the user exists or not, nothing will print, why? Thank you.

Comment: Why would it? `ctx.redirect` is just a statement, and doesn't have any influence on the control flow thus once that statement is executed, it just executes the next statement `console.log`

Comment: And in the example with return, you forgot the braces around your block, thus the return is always executed. Seems you lack knowledge of some very basic principles. Please find some basic tutorials, which will explain the basics of the control flow